# Is it possible to put an ArchLinux .iso on an empty hard drive and then install it on that same drive?

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I have an empty HDD. I would like to avoid using my USB flash as a bootable device. Can I use LinuxLive boot creator to make the HDD bootable and then install the OS on that same HDD? Wouldn't that mess up the bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you willing to create a `/boot` partition that is 1GB?  If yes, then create a 1GB partition at the start drive, drop your iso on it.  Install grub 2 and build a config to boot your ISO.

Then simply reboot and install.  During the install tell the installer to use that first partition for `/boot`.  Simply don't format it.  This has the added advantage of leaving the iso there for rescues, and reinstalls in the future.

Comment: Haven't thought of that- thanks! Simple and elegant.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic Very nice, Zoredache! ext2 partitions are also easily resized down to a more reasonable size (for /boot, 50-100MB can be typical) when the install is completed. In this case leaving a hole for a new partition, or maybe enlarge your swap partition to fill the gap.